# Bad sign if I need a method of a class without calling a constructor because constructor needs parameters?

Tags: php, constructor, static-methods

```
class Test
{
    private $flag;

    public function __construct($flag)
    {
        $this->flag = $flag;
    }

    public function a()
    {
        if ($this->flag)
        {
            $this->b();
        }
    }

    public function b()
    {
        $this->c();
    }

    public function c()
    {
    }
}
```

how an external method would like to use `b()` but he cant do it without creating `Test`. But Test requires a parameter, even though it wont be used. `b()` also cant be static.

Comment: Why is `b` an instance method then if you don't conceptually need an instance to use it? Unless I'm missing something, yes this should be static, or even an external helper.

Comment: ...huh?  Mind clearing up the question?

Comment: You can try defaulting the constructor value: `public function __construct($flag = null)`. Otherwise you need to decide if `b()` really needs to be part of that class.

Comment: Why can't it be static?

Comment: because "B" calls "C", I updated the question

Comment: You cannot use a method without creating an instance of the class. It doesn't make any sense. Methods operates on objects. You can think of methods as properties of the instances. No instances -> no methods available. Static methods are just global functions with fancy names.

Comment: @JohnSmith It would have been nice to see the full picture originally. If b requires use of c, and c requires an instance, then b would need to be an instance method as well, at least without refactoring. Without seeing the real code though, we can only guess.

Comment: Why can't `c` be static?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to original question:
Yep, the best way to access the method of a class without instantiating it (instantiation requires parameters) is to make the desired method static. Make sure that it makes sense to use the method even if the object has not been constructed yet. Note that you cannot refer to non-static content, e.g. non-static methods, within a static context e.g. a static method.

Edit (question now specifies b() cannot be static):
If b() cannot be static then it must be referring to a non-static member e.g. a non-static function or variable. In other words, it must be referring to an instance variable that requires the instantiation of the object. It is not possible to call a non-static method of a class without instantiating the class. I would recommend you analyze the class structure and determine why b() must be non-static (trace any functions or variables it refers to).

Looking at the body of b(), it calls the non-static method c(). Analyze the body of c() and find out why c() must be non-static. If you cannot find any references to an instance of the object, you can safely make c() static and therefore make b() static. On the other hand, if c() requires an instance then b() will also require an instance meaning it is not possible to make b() static.

Comment: sorry, it cant be static... I updated my question too late :)

Comment: A `static` method is just a global function with a fancy name.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create the class without specifying the flag, then you can default the value:

```
public function __construct($flag = null)
{
    $this->flag = $flag;
}
```

You can use other simple values instead of null. If you need to default it to something other than a simple value (i.e. you need to call another function), then you can check to see if `$flag` is null or not null. Then you can use the other functions as necessary.